# Converting Python calculation to Octave code

Tags: python, math, octave

I have a calculation that was created in Python and I'm trying to convert it over to Octave 4.2.2 which is similar to Matlab code.

Python Code:

```
def gcd(a,b):
  if b == 0:
    return a
  else:
    return gcd(b,a%b)

def lcm(a,b):
  return a*b//gcd(a,b)

def NumberOfShifts(m,n):
  N = 1
  l = min(-(-m//2),-(-n//2))
  for k in range(1,l):
    N = lcm(N,2+m+n-4*k)
  return 2*N
```

If ***m*** and ***n*** are both ***5*** the answer should be ***16***.

The Octave / Matlab Code I have so far **doesn't work for cases where m and n are the same odd number any idea how to fix this?**

```
m=5 % doesn't work with same odd numbers like 5
n=5 % doesn't work with same odd numbers like 5
N=1
l=min(-floor(-m/2),-floor(-n/2))
for k=1:l
    N=lcm(N,2+m+n-4*k)
end
final_repeat_loop=2*N  %how many loops to do to repeat
```

**The answer I get is 0.**

Comment: Are you sure that your GCD and LCM work correctly in Matlab?

Comment: `range(1,l)` In python does not include the element l. In Matlab, it does. Could this be the problem? What happens if you try replacing `for k=1:l` with `for k=1:(l-1)`?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin yes changing the loop to `for k=1:(l-1)` did fix it. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'll post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `range(1,l)` does not include the element l (see [here](https://pynative.com/python-range-function/)). 
This is usually a point of confusion for people new to Python - it was and still is for me.

In Matlab, the equivalent `for k=1:l` does include l. So, to switch from Python to Matlab, `range(1,l)` should be replaced with `for k=1:(l-1)`